# Text Input, Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

My friend was showing me a program in shell script where he made where he would open the program, it would ask a question, he would type an answer then it would close but whatever he typed as the answer would be transferred to a text doc can someone please help me I am new, I am using i am using bash and am using ubuntu 13.10

Comment: What is the source code of the shell script? I can't see the script, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Generally Stack Overflow members won't want to write new code for you. It's best to search the internet and try to solve the problem yourself first. Then if you get stuck you can post what you've done and we'll try to help you fix it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a script that asks for input and writes it to a file this is one version:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "What's your name? " input   # prompt for name and store in var
echo "Hello $input!"                 # print greeting
echo $input >> myfile.out            # append to file
```

If you wanted to ask something else please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -e -p "Which atom do you want me to investigate? " atom1
echo $atom1
```

`read -e -p` allows the user to backspace.